# Block arrow in equation

Tags: tikz-arrows

How do I make block arrow in equation? Something like this, but done much more beautifully (smaller arrow):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node [single arrow, draw, minimum height=1ex,minimum width=2ex,inner sep=2ex] {\vphantom{x}};
\end{tikzpicture}
B
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
% with use of "scale" doesn't work
\begin{equation}
A\ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-.75ex,scale=0.5]
\node [single arrow, draw, minimum height=2em,minimum width=2ex] {};
\end{tikzpicture}\ 
B
\end{equation}
% with defining minimum width and single arrow head extend 
\begin{equation}
A\
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-.75ex]
\node [single arrow, draw, minimum height=2em, 
       single arrow head extend=1ex,inner sep=0.5ex] {};
\end{tikzpicture}\
B
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** 
Minimum size of `single arrow` is determined with `inner sep`. make arrow smaller you have two possibilities:

- use `scale` as you suggest in your comment
- define smaler `inner sep` to size at which the arrow will become as you liked and add option `single arrow head extend` for better arrow's looks

Bot solution are  now added in above MWE.

Comment: Yes, something like that. But can you make the arrow smaller vertically?

Comment: Ah, I have figured out. Use scale=.5 to make it smaller. Do you want to add this to your answers? I will accept your answer if you do.

Comment: of course, decrease `inner sep`. see answer edit.

Answer (score 2):

Without using TikZ there is also `\rightwhitearrow` of stix package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    A\,
    \rightwhitearrow
    B   
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]